# xdotool wont work in i3wm when bound to a key

Tags: keyboard, window-managers, xdotool, i3

I have made a script where it uses `xdotool` to do some keyboard inputs.
You can find the script [here](https://pastebin.com/UthyNNYX) (The script is called `pop_mpv.sh`).

The script works perfectly when I run it from a terminal, but it does not work properly when I have the script bound to a key.

This is what I put into my i3 config:

```
bindsym --release $mod+p exec bash ~/bin/pop_mpv.sh
```

According to the i3wm user guide, I have to use `--release` because I am using `xdotool`.
https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings

I tried what suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180405/xdotool-commands-bound-to-key-shortcuts-doesnot-work), but it did not work.

**EDIT** I forgot to add to script that you need `xclip` for it run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script and i3wm keybinding all look correct. It's strange. When I put `sleep 1` before executing bash script. It suddenly works...

```
bindsym --release $mod+p exec "sleep1; ~/bin/pop_mpv.sh"
```